# ShellExecuteEx : get parent PID and close it

Tags: pid, visual-c++-2008, shellexecuteex, close-application

I run a child app using ShellExecuteEx command under windows. Now I want the child app to send a wm_close command to the parent app (the caller of this app) . Is that possible ?

Comment: For getting the parent PID, see [`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`Process32First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanx can you give an example since I never used those functions?

Comment: This [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should help.